# Java: compilation error with the command prompt

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab8 {
          public static void main(String str[]) {
                    List list=new ArrayList();
                    list.add("sri");
                    list.add("Nivas");
                    list.add("Dande");
                    list.add("JLC");
                    System.out.println(list);

                   Iterator it=list.iterator();
                   while(it.hasNext()) {
                               Object obj=it.next();
                               System.out.println(obj);
                               if(obj.equals("JLC")) 
                               it.remove();
                    }
                    System.out.println(list);
          }
}
```

### Problem:

While compiling the above code with an IDE, it works just fine but when I compile it
using the command prompt, the compiler throws an error as:

```
 error: incompatible types
        Object obj=it.next();
                      ^
  required: Object
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

Why I am getting this error with the command prompt and not with the IDE?

Comment: `public static void main(String str[]) {`

Could you change it to the default `public static void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: Do you have another class named `Object`? Other possibilities include a corrupt class-path.

Comment: When you compile it with the command prompt, can you give us the exact command you're using?

Comment: I am also suspecting that there is an issue with type safety. Try using generics.

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
...

String str = it.next(); etc.

Comment: @kevinze, I tried it as per your suggestion but it made no changes

Comment: @BrianEnglish, Here is command:

Comment: Do you have to import java.lang.Object if not using and IDE?

Comment: @BrianEnglish, Here is the command :A:\JavaSpace\UtilPackage>javac Lab8.java
Here UtilPackage is where my Lab8.java file is residing

Comment: @kevinze - The issue here is why OP is getting **this** particular error.  None of your suggestions help in this matter.

Comment: This compile and run fine: see http://ideone.com/39Tk9x Maybe you check your environment

Comment: Do you set `CLASSPATH` environmental variable on your system?

Comment: @kevinze Even that is not workin ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

Comment: @PM77-1 yes sir it's already set. I am learning Java from last 2 months and i haven't received any error till now B4 entering int Collections. One similar problem i got with another program also but i ignored it at that time but when it appeared for 2nd time i could not resist to ask B4 proceeding

Comment: Like @ElliottFrisch says, the problem here seems to be that you have another class named `Object`. Since you don't use generics, an iterator will return a `java.lang.Object`. Rename your own `Object` class to something else.

Comment: @RC. But if there is some problem with the environment then none of the program should have compiled

Comment: My hypothesis is falsifiable; does `java.lang.Object obj=it.next();` work? If so, you have another class named Object.

Comment: @PM 77-1 erm, did you even try my suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried running your code on my system and I got a different error in my command prompt (windows).

```
Note: Lab8.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Well, maybe our system handles this kind of problems a bit differently, but the issue with your code is the lack of generics. You are adding String objects to the List, so you should specify it as such. Without being specific, you could add in String, ints, and other stuff and the subsequent operations that you perform on the objects in the List aren't always guaranteed to work (well in this case, there isn't much of a problem because you're just printing things out, but nonetheless, JVM will still warn you of this before it compiles your code).

Here you go. Notice the use of the angle brackets < > to specify the type more strictly (a good practice in a statically typed language like Java).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Lab8 {
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("sri");
        list.add("Nivas");
        list.add("Dande");
        list.add("JLC");
        System.out.println(list);

        Iterator<String> it=list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Object obj=it.next();
            System.out.println(obj);
            if(obj.equals("JLC")) 
                it.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Eclipse allows your old code to be built and run, but attempting to compile in the command line shows the compilation warning. Why the difference? Well, Eclipse assumes that you have read its compilation warnings already (which are displayed in the IDE itself by the left of the code, with a tiny light bulb symbol), and hence lets you build and run the program if you so desire. There is no such feature in the command line, so they have to give you some explicit warning message.

In any case, I hope you do not have any more errors using the code I provided. If you still have errors, then maybe it is another issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ,Actually the error(warning message) which you are telling about is something which i am getting with every compilation of programs related to Collections. However the code you provided below just works fine with my command prompt. So thank you very much for your efforts in solving my problem.

Comment: That's great and I'm glad to have been able to help. Good luck!